# Proof verification: Every group of order n! contains non trivial normal subgroup (without Sylow)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Suppose $ |G| = n!$ then 
either

$ G \simeq S_{n} $ $=>$ the preimage of $A_{n}$ is a normal subgroup which means that G contains a non trivial normal subgroup

or
if $G$ is not isomorph there is a Grouphomomorphism to $S_{n}$ because the order of $G$ is finite but since they are not isomorph the homomorphism is not injective therefore we can choose a kernel and are done

is this correct or am i missing something?

Comment: You better add "a **non-trivial** normal subgroup..." before someone comes and comment/answer that $\;\{1\}\;$ is always a normal subgroup...Besides this and to the point: can you **prove** that there's always a homomorphism (from $\;G\,$) to $\;S_n\;$? This doesn't look easy to wave off and it doesn't follow from Cayley theorem as there it is shown $\;G\;$ is isomorphic with a subgroup of $\;S_{n!}\;$ ...

Comment: Every group contains itself and the zero group as normal subgroup. Is it the intention to prove that a group of order $n!$ is not simple?

Comment: @DonAntonio I see, so if G is isomorphic to a non normal subgroup of $S_{n!}$ i have to use Sylowtheorems to prove this ?

Comment: @BartimäusvonUruk Perhaps so. I really don't know right now. Perhaps I'll think of something later.

Comment: So you are saying that there is no finite simple group of order $n!$ That might be right, but why do you think so?

Answer (score 1):

As observed in the comments, the proof proposed in the OP is incorrect because Cayley's theorem does not guarantee a group homomorphism to $S_n$.

Since $|G| = n!$, what it guarantees is an *embedding* into the much bigger group $S_{n!}$. Since the map constructed this way is injective, it does not hand you the kernel you want.

Your claimed result seems likely to me (that $n!$ is not the order of a finite simple group - I can't think of a finite simple group with factorial order), but it is hard for me to imagine a proof that doesn't use Sylow theory or something more advanced (like the classification theorem).